# How to render code from db and make it work in erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-7

I have some markup like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" 
content="text/html; charset=utf-8">  <title>something<title><......
```

Embedded with ruby tags like this:

```
Hi, <%=@user.name%>
```

I stored this all file code in database column, and now I want to make this code work but coming from the database - how can I do that?

```
<%= @emaildetail.description %>
```

I have tried `html_safe` but that doesn't make the ruby code and variables work

Comment: Note that ERB can embed arbitrary Ruby code. As such, the ERB templates you store in your database can execute any arbitrary Ruby code and thus have access to all data and all code in your application and on your server. This may be a large security risk. Make really sure that only users you trust with full code execution on your server can edit these database values. The same security precautions apply as when using `eval` with user-supplied code.

Comment: Wrote you an example below. You just need to define both instance variables in your mailer method. Be very careful about what you choose to render as `html_safe` / never use it on any strings that could potentially contain malicious code or you are risking a security incident.

Answer (score 1):

The ruby tags you're seeing is called [ERB](https://github.com/ruby/erb)

Here is a minimal example how to use it.

```
require 'erb'

x = 42
template = ERB.new <<-EOF
  The value of x is: <%= x %>
EOF
puts template.result(binding)
```

In your case the template content would come from the database rather than from the code, but the rest should work the same.

This will resolve all the ruby code and variables. You will still have to call `.html_safe` on it to also render it as html.

Comment: it worked with just rendering this inline in same file like <%= render :inline => @emaildetail.description%>

this , thanks much for replying

Answer (score 0):

Take some time to read [Rails Guide: Action Mailer Basics](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#edit-the-mailer), it should tell you everything you need to know. There are a bunch of ways to implement something like this, but here's a very primitive example:

##### `app/models/mail_detail.rb`:

```rb
class MailDetail
  belongs_to :user

  validates :recipient, presence: true
  validates :custom_body, presence: true
end
```

##### `app/mailers/custom_mailer.rb`:

```rb
class CustomMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def custom_message
    @detail = params[:maildetail]
    # You can also pass user as a param, but ideally there is a model association
    @user = @detail.user

    # Users change their email addresses, store it on your detail record
    # if you need to retain an accurate history
    mail to: @detail.recipient, subject: @detail.subject
  end
end
```

##### `app/views/custom_mailer/custom_message.html.erb`:

```rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi, <%= @user.first_name %></h1>
    <div><%= @detail.custom_body.html_safe %></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

*This is a primitive example of something that works, *not* explicit guidance on yielding custom content into a template. Rails escapes unsafe strings by default, so you must mark the string as safe to tell Rails that the string is not malicious — **using this to render unsanitized content generated from user input opens you up to a cross-site-scripting vulnerability!***

[Preview your mailer](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#previewing-emails) at `http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/custom_mailer/custom_message`

##### Sending

Sending the email would look something like this:

```rb
CustomMailer.with(mail_detail: some_email_detail_record).custom_message.deliver_now
```

The [ActionMailer::Parameterized::ClassMethods#with](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Parameterized/ClassMethods.html#method-i-with) method is what defines the `params` available to your mailer method.

Alternatively, you could define your mailer method with named arguments instead:

```rb
def custom_message(detail:)
  @detail = detail
  @user = detail.user
  mail to: @detail.recipient, subject: @detail.subject
end
```

And send it via:

```rb
CustomMailer.custom_message(detail: some_email_detail_record).deliver_now
```